# Cannot connect to grafana using port

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, grafana

Below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.2'

services:
 mysql-server:
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
        - "13306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
        MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
        MYSQL_USER: wordpress_user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    image: mysql/mysql-server
 grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    environment:
        DB_HOST: mysql-server:3306
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - mysql-server
```

I would like to connect to grafana and use mysql to be my datasource.
However, when I connect to grafana using 'container ip address + port' 172.19.0.3 (retrieved by using 'docker inspect containerID'):3306. It cannot connect to grafana. I tried to close my firewall but still failed. Or my method of connection is wrong?

Besides, when I set MySQL as datasource in grafana, is the host be: mysql-server:3306?

Comment: I think you must separate DB_HOST and DB_PORT variables. Could you try to put `DB_HOST: mysql-server` and `DB_PORT: 3306`  as env vars for your grafana service ? Also, I'm not 100% sure but you probably need to specify the following env vars : `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD`

Comment: I think you're using incorrect environment variable(s). It should be  [`GF_DATABASE_HOST: mysql-server:3306`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#configure-with-environment-variables). Also, you should be able to connect to Grafana via `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

So far you have not cared about networking of the two containers. Yes, both of them expose a port on the host - but you are not trying to access that one. Instead you are trying to make a connection from one container directly to the other container.

- First step is to [create a bridged network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).
- Then define both containers [to be connected to that network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#connect-a-container-to-a-user-defined-bridge).
- Finally you can use the name of one container as hostname to connect from the other container.